# specify a property editor inside the business object

Tags: entity-framework, devexpress, xaf

I am using `Dev Express` `XAF` with `Entity framework`.
I want to be able to specify that my `Description` field uses property editor `DevExpress.ExpressApp.HtmlPropertyEditor.Win.HtmlPropertyEditor`

I can do this by setting the property editor inside `model.xafml` in the views that involve the field. However I would prefer to just set it once in the `business` object as an attribute.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DevExpress knowledge base explains how to achieve this here: [KA18907](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/KA18907). See section 2.2 and 2.3.

If your business object is declared in the same module as the editor, then you can do this:

```
//Class declared in a WinForms module, for example
public class BusinessObject : BaseObject {
    ...
    [ModelDefault("PropertyEditorType", "SampleSolution.Module.Win.PropertyEditors.CustomStringEditor")]
    public string Description {
        get { return GetPropertyValue<string>("Description"); }
        set { SetPropertyValue<string>("Description", value); }
    }
}
```

Otherwise, use the `EditorAlias` attribute instead.

```
public class BusinessObject : BaseObject {
    ...
    [EditorAlias("CustomStringEdit")]
    public string Description {
        get { return GetPropertyValue<string>("Description"); }
        set { SetPropertyValue<string>("Description", value); }
    }
}
```

and set the same string identifier in your editor. (This allows different editors to be specified separate Web and Win modules).

```
[PropertyEditor(typeof(String), "CustomStringEdit", false)]
public class CustomStringEditor : StringPropertyEditor {
    public CustomStringEditor(Type objectType, IModelMemberViewItem info)
        : base(objectType, info) {  }
    ...
}
```

Comment: I have the business object declared in the platform independent module. I need it there because this is where the Entity Framework Context is.

Comment: So use `EditorAlias` as explained in 2.3.